# AutoIt _WinAPI_UniqueHardwareID

Tags: winapi, autoit

I am using AutoIt to detect unique hardware ID. Here is my code:

```
#include <WinAPIEx.au3>
$hardwareid = _WinAPI_UniqueHardwareID()
ConsoleWrite ($hardwareid)
```

The generated hardware ID is depending on what hardware component? If I change or add harddrive or ram will that change the generated `hardwareid`?

Comment: Ofcourse it will change.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use hardware to create unique ID, your best chance is to use only one hardware. Use CPU or Motherboard.

I suggest you also write somewhere that hidden IDs of all hardware and do some comparing, so you can avoid changing ID by changing single hardware.

```
; Generated by AutoIt Scriptomatic

$wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 0x10
$wbemFlagForwardOnly = 0x20
$colItems = ""
$strComputer = "localhost"

$Output=""
$Output = $Output & "Computer: " & $strComputer  & @CRLF
$Output = $Output & "==========================================" & @CRLF
$objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\" & $strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
$colItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", _
                                          $wbemFlagReturnImmediately + $wbemFlagForwardOnly)

If IsObj($colItems) then
   For $objItem In $colItems
      $Output = $Output & "AddressWidth: " & $objItem.AddressWidth & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Architecture: " & $objItem.Architecture & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Availability: " & $objItem.Availability & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Caption: " & $objItem.Caption & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ConfigManagerErrorCode: " & $objItem.ConfigManagerErrorCode & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ConfigManagerUserConfig: " & $objItem.ConfigManagerUserConfig & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "CpuStatus: " & $objItem.CpuStatus & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "CreationClassName: " & $objItem.CreationClassName & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "CurrentClockSpeed: " & $objItem.CurrentClockSpeed & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "CurrentVoltage: " & $objItem.CurrentVoltage & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "DataWidth: " & $objItem.DataWidth & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Description: " & $objItem.Description & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "DeviceID: " & $objItem.DeviceID & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ErrorCleared: " & $objItem.ErrorCleared & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ErrorDescription: " & $objItem.ErrorDescription & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ExtClock: " & $objItem.ExtClock & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Family: " & $objItem.Family & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "InstallDate: " & WMIDateStringToDate($objItem.InstallDate) & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "L2CacheSize: " & $objItem.L2CacheSize & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "L2CacheSpeed: " & $objItem.L2CacheSpeed & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "LastErrorCode: " & $objItem.LastErrorCode & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Level: " & $objItem.Level & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "LoadPercentage: " & $objItem.LoadPercentage & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Manufacturer: " & $objItem.Manufacturer & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "MaxClockSpeed: " & $objItem.MaxClockSpeed & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Name: " & $objItem.Name & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "OtherFamilyDescription: " & $objItem.OtherFamilyDescription & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "PNPDeviceID: " & $objItem.PNPDeviceID & @CRLF
      $strPowerManagementCapabilities = $objItem.PowerManagementCapabilities(0)
      $Output = $Output & "PowerManagementCapabilities: " & $strPowerManagementCapabilities & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "PowerManagementSupported: " & $objItem.PowerManagementSupported & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ProcessorId: " & $objItem.ProcessorId & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "ProcessorType: " & $objItem.ProcessorType & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Revision: " & $objItem.Revision & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Role: " & $objItem.Role & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "SocketDesignation: " & $objItem.SocketDesignation & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Status: " & $objItem.Status & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "StatusInfo: " & $objItem.StatusInfo & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Stepping: " & $objItem.Stepping & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "SystemCreationClassName: " & $objItem.SystemCreationClassName & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "SystemName: " & $objItem.SystemName & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "UniqueId: " & $objItem.UniqueId & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "UpgradeMethod: " & $objItem.UpgradeMethod & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "Version: " & $objItem.Version & @CRLF
      $Output = $Output & "VoltageCaps: " & $objItem.VoltageCaps & @CRLF
      if Msgbox(1,"WMI Output",$Output) = 2 then ExitLoop
      $Output=""
   Next
Else
   Msgbox(0,"WMI Output","No WMI Objects Found for class: " & "Win32_Processor" )
Endif


Func WMIDateStringToDate($dtmDate)

    Return (StringMid($dtmDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
    StringMid($dtmDate, 7, 2) & "/" & StringLeft($dtmDate, 4) _
    & " " & StringMid($dtmDate, 9, 2) & ":" & StringMid($dtmDate, 11, 2) & ":" & StringMid($dtmDate,13, 2))
EndFunc
```